# In bndtools, what causes a Require-Capability header for execution environment to be generated?

Tags: osgi, bnd, bndtools

I have the following bnd file:

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.12
Bundle-Activator: a.b.Activator
Private-Package: a.b
-buildpath: osgi.core;version=4.3.0,\
    org.apache.felix.bundlerepository;version=1.6.6,\
    osgi.cmpn;version=4.3.0.201111022214
-sources: false
```

In the generated MANIFEST.MF:

```
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))"
```

I don't want this there... there's no reason I can see that it should be. So how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

bnd 2.3 automatically adds this. You can disable with `-noee=true` in your bnd file.

Generally this is a good requirement to have since it expresses the base JRE requirement of your bundle. bnd determines the version based upon the class file versions in the bundle.

Comment: Ah yeah - sorry this is a "unbounded" version range so it means 1.6 and later... so my concern that this would require _exactly_ 1.6 is invalid. D'oh.

Comment: If you are wondering how to do that with the `maven-bundle-plugin`, use the following instruction:

    <_noee>true<_noee>

Comment: Great this works! You're missing a slash here. So when you're copy/pasting use this instead: <_noee>true</_noee>