# Force maven-bundle-plugin to use a specific osgi.ee Require-Capability

Tags: maven, osgi-bundle, bndtools, maven-bundle-plugin

We are building a OSGi bundle using maven-bundle-plugin. The default configuration works good but the problem arises when deploying the bundle in a container. Running `jdeps` on the jar shows the code is compatible with compact1 profile and I would like to force maven-bundle-plugin to use compact1 instead of the derived JavaSE 1.8. How can we achieve this?

We don't want to use `_noee` just to be on the safe side because of an earlier [advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851771/in-bndtools-what-causes-a-require-capability-header-for-execution-environment-t).

[FELIX-6199](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-6199) is a related issue.